# existing circuit box without ground wire

Tags: wiring

I have a outlet box with 12/2 wiring ungrounded.  Can I legally just run a separate grounding wire to the nearest circuit box that is grounded?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

You can if both are supplied from the same panel. This was not legal in the past but current code allows it.

Comment: I think they made it legal because everyone was doing it. +

Comment: I don’t know I had never done it or seen it done but had heard of it. I do think it makes sense as it in a perfect world it will never have current on it.